Separate a column with hybrid data types in polars
I have column with containing data of multiple data types as string. Now, I am wondering how I can split the data into separate columns (one for each data type).
Input.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "hybrid_column": ["1", "hello", "{'a': 1}", "True"]
})

Output.
shape: (4, 5)
┌───────────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────────┬─────────┐
│ hybrid_column │ integer │ string │ struct     │ boolean │
│ ---           │ ---     │ ---    │ ---        │ ---     │
│ str           │ i64     │ str    │ struct[?]  │ bool    │
├───────────────┼─────────┼────────┼────────────┼─────────┤
│ 1             │ 1       │ null   │ null       │ null    │
│ hello         │ null    │ hello  │ null       │ null    │
│ {'a': 1}      │ null    │ null   │ {"a": 1}   │ null    │
│ True          │ null    │ null   │ null       │ true    │
└───────────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────────┴─────────┘


Can hybrid_column contain multiple structs of different types? Lists? How do you end up with such a column in the first place? Is it the result of another Polars operation?

No, it is part of the payload, some of the columns in the payload have hybrid of string and dict.


cast() with strict parameter set to False to cast to int.
replace_strict() to cast to bool.
str.contains() for some crude regex check.
str.json_decode() to convert str to struct.
all_horizontal() to check if all new columns are empty so we can put remaining data into str column.
when/then() to create str column.

df.with_columns(
    int_column = pl.col.hybrid_column.cast(pl.Int32, strict=False),
    boolean_column = pl.col.hybrid_column.replace_strict({"False": False, "True": True}, default = None),
    struct_column = pl.when(pl.col.hybrid_column.str.contains(r"\{*\}")).then(pl.col.hybrid_column)
).with_columns(
    pl.col.struct_column.str.json_decode(),
    str_column = pl.when(pl.all_horizontal(pl.exclude("hybrid_column").is_null())).then(pl.col.hybrid_column)
)

┌───────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┬───────────────┬────────────┐
│ hybrid_column ┆ int_column ┆ boolean_column ┆ struct_column ┆ str_column │
│ ---           ┆ ---        ┆ ---            ┆ ---           ┆ ---        │
│ str           ┆ i32        ┆ bool           ┆ struct[1]     ┆ str        │
╞═══════════════╪════════════╪════════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════╡
│ 1             ┆ 1          ┆ null           ┆ {null}        ┆ null       │
│ hello         ┆ null       ┆ null           ┆ {null}        ┆ hello      │
│ {"a": 1}      ┆ null       ┆ null           ┆ {1}           ┆ null       │
│ True          ┆ null       ┆ true           ┆ {null}        ┆ null       │
└───────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴───────────────┴────────────┘

